# Authentication between PC and Android

Tags: android, authentication

I am writing an Android app that connects to a datacenter (Windows PC) that is used to serve data, such as FTP server and other files. I need the app to authenticate to the datacenter with a username and password, so that you have to log in before you can access anything on the PC. I am familiar with logging in to a site with PHP, but never anything other than a website. I have found some information on Apache Shiro or Spring Security, but I can't find any simple examples of them. Also, a bonus would be it could work as a proxy, blocking traffic to the PC when not logged in, and allowing traffic when logged in. Can anyone recommend a simple method to authenticate my app with the PC?

Comment: `need the app to authenticate to the datacenter`. Pretty vague. Which protocol? What kind of datacenter server?

Comment: I haven't really figured out a protocol to do this, that is the problem. The datacenter is really acting as more of a point of entry to a network, and it is running a MySQL database to log traffic information, but it is not serving a website or anything. What I am calling the datacenter is just a Windows 10 pc with MySQL installed and Wireshark to log traffic data.

Comment: 'I haven't really figured out a protocol to do this,'. ??? You do not have to make a protocol. You have to figure out which protocol is used for that. So which protocol you have to use. Once you know you can implement that protocol.

Comment: It is unclear to me to which/what you have to authenticate.

Comment: I will try to explain it better. I have my android app, which needs to use a user name and password to authenticate with the datacenter. You open the app, log in, and if the login is accepted you can access data on the datacenter, or on the network the datacenter is on. If you do not log in, you cannot access the database or the network the datacenter is on.

Comment: All makes no sense. And you still did not tell with who the app has to connect in order to that all. Where does the app have to log in. Who is accepting the log in? Do not use the name datacenter but come to the point.

Comment: The app should send a message to the windows pc, it would check the login and password against an approved list (which could be stored in the sql database or not), and then approves or denies the user. The closest thing I can compare it to is a proxy server, but I need to implement it natively in my android app without using a proxy app, and it needs to control access on all ports, not just http (80).

Answer (score 0):

In Apache Server your php code is

```
<?PHP
    $con=
    "(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = your_ip)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = database_name)
    )
    )";
    $conn = ocilogon( "User_name", "password",$con,"WE8ISO8859P15");

    $query = "Select * from tablename"; 

    $parseresults = ociparse($conn, $query);
    ociexecute($parseresults);

     while($row=oci_fetch_assoc($parseresults))

     $output[]=$row;

     print json_encode($output);

    oci_free_statement($parseresults);
    oci_close($conn);
    ?>
```

In Android you can use

```
public class UploadAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
Context context;

String result;

public UploadActivity(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();


}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    final List<Pair<String, String>> postParameters = new ArrayList<>();



    Database db= new Database(context);
    db.open();
    String activity[][] = db.uploadActivity();
    db.close();
    if(activity!=null&&!activity[0].equals(null) ) {
        for (int i = 0; i < activity[0].length; i++) {

            postParameters.add(new Pair<>("var1", activity[i][0]);

            result = null;


            try {

                String response = CustomHttpClient.execute(
                        URL + "UPLOAD_DATA.php", postParameters);
                result = response.toString();
                result = result.replaceAll("(\r\n|\n)", "");

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e("log_tag_ms", "Error in http connection!!" + e.toString());

            }

        }
    }

    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);


    } 
 }
```

Comment: All your code does not make sense as OP asked for other info.

Comment: Sorry I can't understand you